# Display all site collections on web application home page

Tags: 2010, site-collection, web-application

I have a web application in my SP 2010 farm with the url as:

```
http://servername
```

I have 3 site collections in this web application as:

- /
- /sites/it
- /sites/finance

When I browse to the url http://server/, it does not list all my site collections on the top bar. How can I display all my site collections on my web application home page?

Comment: As you accepted Alexander's answer i asume you are talking about an manual solution to add the links. You should update your question to reflect this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to **Site Settings** -> **Look and feel** -> **Top Link bar** (if you use publishing feature **Site Settings** -> **Look and feel** -> **Navigation**  and use Global navigation). In these settings you can add links of your sites that should be displayed in top bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can add link manualy by using Content Editor Web Part or add it to quick launch.

If you need authomaticly display link to all site collections, you have to write your simple custom web part with using collection SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.Sites.

Comment: But in MOSS 2007, they were displayed automatically at the web app level. Is there a change in functionality in 2010?

Comment: No there is no change from 2007 to 2010. The only option to display hierachy information is within a site collection.